# How to track multi-touch using FreeGLUT or GLUT?

Tags: c, opengl, glut, multi-touch, freeglut

I'm trying to track multi-touch in FreeGLUT

When I just tracked one point, I used [`glutMouseFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node50.html).

I heard that I cannot track many mice in GLUT, and in FreeGLUT I can.

So here are my questions:

1. How can I track multiple touches in FreeGLUT?
2. Could you show me some examples or explain the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `glutMulti*Func()` callback setters](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut/blob/v3.2.2/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h#L213-L224):

```
// glutEntryFunc()
void glutMultiEntryFunc( void (* callback)( int, int ) );

// glutMouseFunc()
void glutMultiButtonFunc( void (* callback)( int, int, int, int, int ) );

// glutMotionFunc()
void glutMultiMotionFunc( void (* callback)( int, int, int ) );

// glutPassiveMotionFunc()
void glutMultiPassiveFunc( void (* callback)( int, int, int ) );
```

[Documentation](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#MultiTouch) ([doc source](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut_website/blob/f523045e934ab43a1bea55b6afe0630986308f25/docs/api.php#L2767-L2814)):

> These functions work like their non-multi variants, with an additional 'deviceid' parameter describing the current input device (mouse or finger).
>
> Exception: in MultiButtonFunc, the order of callback parameters is different (x,y,button,state instead of button,state,x,y).
>
> Currently, under X11, the non-multi callback variants are also called on X11 for each event.
>
> Currently, under windows, the first (oldest) touch point also controls the mouse cursor, which triggers the non-multi callbacks as usual.
>
> All these functions have user-data callback functions.

[The FreeGLUT Git repository](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut) has [a multi-touch demo](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut/blob/v3.2.2/progs/demos/multi-touch/multi-touch.c).